# How to clear MySQL deterministic function result cache?

Tags: mysql, function, caching, mariadb, deterministic

I have a huge Geo database that I frequently need to compare with real time Geo data in order to determine nearest location per Latitude:Longitude. The location table does hold a number of rows, but is rarely added with new records. Determining nearest location against millions of real time data is painfully costing us with super slow queries, even after implementing a rectangular distance comparison algorithm (than actually comparing by Haversine).

I want to convert this comparison with a DETERMINISTIC function that should really bring up a real performance boost with static results.

However, I want MySQL to reset/rebuild this deterministic result cache every week. Like, I want MySQL to return me the same result for a Latitude:Longitude pair comparing against my location table, but for 7 days. After 7 days, there is a good chance I might add new locations to that table, and I want MySQL to start rebuilding that deterministic function result cache considering new rows been added to that table, preferably without restarting MySQL server.

**Note**: A MariaDB compliant solution is a serious good to have :)

**Correction**: Please forgive me to use that term with MySQL. So far I could understand, the result does not change for a deterministic function where all input are the same, this allures me to think MySQL does not actually tend to execute or process the instruction inside the function, rather returns the previously calculated value for the same set of input values, so, definitely it does cache the values somewhere (I don't know where), thus behaving something like just looking up through a list or something like that. I think I overloaded the OPTIMIZER with CACHE here :(

======== EDIT FOR TECHNICAL CLARIFICATION ========

```
Table: data (around 4.5 Bl records)
ID BIGINT(20) PK AI
Terminal BIGINT(20) NOT NULL <= Foreign key
Latitude FLOAT (8, 5) NULL (indexed)
Longitude FLOAT (8, 5) NULL (indexed)
Location <= Foreign key

Table: location (around 10k records)
ID BIGINT(20) PK AI
Name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL UNIQUE
Latitude FLOAT (8, 5) NOT NULL (indexed)
Longitude FLOAT (8, 5) NOT NULL (indexed)
```

Incoming data for 'data' table is real time and about 1500 data per second (we have a process that iterates indefinitely per second). Around 85% of data contain coordinates and we are trying to determine the nearest location real time as the stream is captured in real time.

Comment: I don't know who tells you that the output of the deterministic function is cached somewhere... but he played a prank on you.

Comment: @Akina Please forgive me to use that term with MySQL. So far I could understand, the result does not change for a deterministic function where all input are the same, this allures me to think MySQL does not actually tend to execute or process the instruction inside the function, rather returns the previously calculated value for the same set of input values, so, definitely it does cache the values somewhere (I don't know where), thus behaving something like just looking up through a list or something like that.

I think I overloaded the OPTIMIZER with CACHE here :(

Comment: Have you considered posting the complete QUERY that is driving you up the wall?  EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query) would give us some useful information to identify opportunities to improve response time.  We will likely ask for A) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; and B) SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name; and C) SHOW TABLE STATUS tbl_name; for each table involved in the query.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Hi, just added the technical clarification section to my original question for a clearer understanding. Thank you for your interest :)

Comment: @BrokenArrow The added information is similar only to SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; output.  Still can not see your QUERY or EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query); or SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name; or SHOW TABLE STATUS tbl_name;  We can help you get to your destination quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `DETERMINISTIC` means as an option to `CREATE FUNCTION`.

It does not mean the result of the function is [memoized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). There is no cache of function results. There is no command to refresh this cache, because the results are not kept.

The meaning of `DETERMINISTIC` mainly affects binary logging:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-function/#not-deterministic

> The `[NOT] DETERMINISTIC` clause also affects binary logging, because the `STATEMENT` format can not be used to store or replicate non-deterministic statements.

That is, a non-deterministic function may return different results if it is executed on a replica, so if you use the function in an SQL statement that modifies data, the binary log format for that event must be `ROW` to ensure the same change is applied on the replica.

There's also a vague reference:

> The optimizer may choose a faster execution plan if it known that the function is deterministic.

But no example is given for such a case. This is likely to be a rarity for it to make a significant performance difference.

I don't think this will be an effective performance optimization for your use case.

Comment: Please forgive me to use that term with MySQL. So far I could understand, the result does not change for a deterministic function where all input are the same, this allures me to think MySQL does not actually tend to execute or process the instruction inside the function, rather returns the previously calculated value for the same set of input values, so, definitely it does cache the values somewhere (I don't know where), thus behaving something like just looking up through a list or something like that. I think I overloaded the OPTIMIZER with CACHE here :(

Comment: That is not how MySQL/MariaDB stored functions work. You have an incorrect understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The Function is not where you can get performance.  (Bill discussed that.)  The algorithm is where you can gain performance.  (I will go into that.)

The simple-minded choice involves checking the distance each of the million rows.  As you have found, this is not scalable.

Next comes `INDEX(lat, lng), INDEX(lng, lat)` and using a bounding box.  That gives an order of magnitude speedup.

A similar improvement comes from using `SPATIAL` values and index.

I go into detail about those 3 approaches in [*Find Nearest*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql) .  That link also gives two algorithms that are another order of magnitude faster, but you may not need that much improvement (and complexity) for only a few million rows.